# Error when trying to install PHP curl - Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: php, ubuntu, curl

When I try to run **sudo apt-get install php5-curl**

I get an error

```
php5-curl : Depends: php5-common (= 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.14) but 5.5.12+dfsg-2ubuntu4.6 is to be installed
```

What does  this mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: IMHO you should ask this question over at http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Looks like some dependency. Hope this will help you.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/340723/cannot-install-php-curl-php5-common-discrepency

Comment: i think ,you should install php5 first

Answer (score 1):

```
apt-get install php5 (or php5-core or php5-common)
apt-get install php5-curl
```